# rails 3: how create a time from hash, like Time.local, except interpret the hash as being in a different time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Given a hash containing time and day, how do I create a time object that is UTC when the hash is some other time zone?

For example, my User is EST and specifies "15:04 8/25/2012" (via a select_datetime in a view) so the time is implicitly EST.

When they submit the form, time_hash = {"day"=>"25", "month"=>"8", "year"=>"2012", "hour"=>"15", "minute"=>"04"}

If I set

```
the_time = Time.local params[:date][:year], params[:date][:month], params[:date][:day], params[:date][:hour], params[:date][:minute]
```

it creates a time object that is 15:04 8/25/2012 -- BUT in the SERVER's local time (Pacific), not the User's local time (Eastern).

Note: I DO have Time.zone set to Eastern earlier in the same method, so I thought Time.local would interpret the hash as Eastern time, but it doesn't. I also tried Time.zone.local but that throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.zone.local
```

should work fine. It's a little picker than `Time.local` and will only accept integers as its arguments, whereas `Time.local` doesn't mind strings. Sprinkle some calls to `to_i` in there and you should be ok.

Comment: Bingo - thanks - the error I was getting when I tried Time.zone.local was due to needing integers and the hash was strings. Odd that Time.local accepts strings and Time.zone.local doesn't but THANKS for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

One trick seems to be: use Time.zone.parse and which also means manually converting the hash to the "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00" format.

```
the_time = Time.zone.parse("#{params[:date][:year]}-#{params[:date][:month]}-#{params[:date][:day]} #{params[:date][:hour]}:#{params[:date][:minute]}:00")
```